# permissions issue with symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i run ./symfony project:permissions

then get:
 Permissions on the following file(s) could not be fixed:

- SF_ROOT_DIR/log

how must i fix this from the command line please?
i have php script im running that creates a .txt file and writes to it, but it is not creating the file...is it because of the permissions issue??

```
a12:/home/rainbowcode# ls -lah
total 21M
drwxr-xr-x  4 rainbowcode rainbowcode 4.0K 2011-04-20 07:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root        root        4.0K 2011-04-13 06:53 ..
-rw-------  1 rainbowcode rainbowcode 4.6K 2011-04-20 10:02 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 rainbowcode rainbowcode  220 2011-01-14 10:42 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 rainbowcode rainbowcode 2.9K 2011-01-14 10:42 .bashrc
-rw-------  1 rainbowcode rainbowcode 1.3K 2011-04-05 12:37 .mysql_history
-rw-r--r--  1 rainbowcode rainbowcode  586 2011-01-14 10:42 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  4 rainbowcode rainbowcode 4.0K 2011-04-20 07:10 rainbowcode_deploy_versions
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root         21M 2011-04-19 07:23 rainbowcode_deploy_versions.zip
drwxr-xr-x  9 root        root        4.0K 2011-03-11 07:49 traffic_2
-rw-------  1 rainbowcode rainbowcode  13K 2011-04-20 07:50 .viminfo
```

the above directory is where i want to write the .txt file to
and the command is:

> a12:/home/rainbowcode# php -q rainbowcode_deploy_versions/0.4.0/web/DB-Query-Script.php

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ownership of the directory...run `ls -al` and look at the user and group.  Also, look at the mode (e.g. `rwxr-xr-x`).  Paste that in your original question and I can help you with the `chown` and `chmod` command options you'll need.

Comment: i did a mkdir /log, ran the permissions and all ok now but then ran the script again and it is not creating my file?? in home/rainbowcode dir??

Comment: @Helloise Smit - glad I could help.